# VC dimension bound of a union of mapping hypothesis sets

Tags: geometry, machine-learning

Consider the following feature transform, which maps a d-dimensional $x$ to a one-dimension $z$, keeping only the $k$th coordinate of $x$

$\phi_{(k)}(x)=(1,x_k)$

Let $H_k$ be the set of perceptrons in the feature space.

Prove that  $d_{vc}(\cup_{k=1}^dH_k) \leq 2(\log_2d+1)$.

I have no idea about this question, for I do not know how to introduce the $\log_2$ int my inequality.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  The present Question looks like you are "passing along" an assigned exercise without evident digestion of the difficulty or meaning of the problem.  "I have no idea about this question" is perhaps an indication that you need to step back from it and ask instead for help understanding the definitions or motivations for the problem.  Presumably it was an exercise intended to reinforce your understanding of some recently studied material, but Readers will have to guess at what that material might be.  You should be our expert in *adding more context*.

Comment: Honestely, this is an exercise from "learning from data" book. These days I am learning this course by myself. Although there is a forum about this book and some problems, I didn't find the specific answer there. You can refer to this (http://book.caltech.edu/bookforum/). I have been stuck in this problem for two days and sadly, still no idea about this.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  After I look at the link there, I'll probably have a suggestion about what to edit into the body of the Question for added context.